# Jquery hashchange automaticly use all functions from file

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I've been using this code to change part of my page using the hashchange function:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
window[location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length)]();
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
window[location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length)]();
});
switch(location.hash.substr(1)) {
case 'foo': foo(); break;
case 'bar': bar(); break;
```

I'm wondering if there a way I can check an external script - hashchange.js - and if the hash matches a function name run that function?

Comment: The functions included in your `hashchange.js` will be loaded into the global context, so `window[location.hash.substring(1)]` will be fine. It only becomes a problem if your `hashchange.js` file creates a closure that encapsulates the functions you want access to.

Comment: Oh, yep, that works fine. Thank you!